# Expressjs: Rendering views depending on application state

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, pug

I'm creating express app and my app accomodates two states- logged in user and anonymous user. My app doesn't require user to login in order to view the content of the site. Currently, the state is determined by the cookie, if myapp_token cookie is present, then app uses the value of this cookie for making API requests (I can't change this behavior).

I need to renders some views in my express app differently depending if the user signed in or not. For example, I have a top nav where, if signed in, user profile picture is displayed and if not I want to show 'log in' link etc.

Some other views will be changed depending on the state as well, hope you got an idea.

My problem is to determine the approach I should use to handle this. My initial idea was to create middleware which would set the `app.local.session` variable depending on the state and then I would access it in my views and there have conditional that would check on what to print.

```
// session.js    
module.exports = function(app) {
        return function(req, res, next) {
            if(req.cookies['app_token']) {
                var session = new Session(req.cookies['app_token']);
                res.locals.session = session.user;
            } else {
                console.log('nothing... ' + req.cookies['app_token']);
            }
            next();
        };
    };
```

My session.js is making http request to my api server to get user info, then it stores the user data in session.user field.

```
 // navbar.jade 
   ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
        li: a(href="#")#profile-fix
        img(alt="" src="#{session.userProfile.imageUrl}").profile-img
        span.user-name #{session.userProfile.userName}
```

I thought that app.locals would be availiable in my view. But I get an error `Cannot read property 'imageUrl' of undefined`
My routes look like this.

```
// routes.js
var routes = require('./handlers');
var session = require('./middlewares/session');


module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/*', session(app), routes.index);
    // app.get('/logout', session.logout);
    app.get('/:location?/:category?', routes.index);
}
```

The way I did it is probably nasty (I'm new to node), the reason behind this `app.get('/*', session(app), routes.index);` is that I wanted to check for session state only on route requests. I tried to do `app.use(....)`, but it would run middleware on static file requests too.

P.S.: How do I debug views in node? For example, how do I find what variables are available and what they contain in a particular view?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing any major issues with what you're doing... To debug, you can console.log(locals). Locals is what express uses for local variables (res.locals, and app.locals).

Comment: You can do that in jade like so: `-console.log(locals)`

Comment: Thanks for reply! I guess the problem is that the view renders before I get session loaded with the data. What I need is to wait for getUserInfo() api call to finish and only after I got it render the view... Any suggestions on how can I do that?

Comment: Added an official answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see your call to getUserInfo, but I'm assuming it has a callback. So what I'd do is this:

```
// session.js    
module.exports = function(app) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        //make API call
        //assuming one of the params is a callback
        getUserInfo(function(err, data){
           if (err) return next(err); //if you want to cause an error

            if (data) {
               res.locals.session = data.user;
            } else {
              console.log('nothing... ' + data);
            }
           next();
       }

      }); 


    };
};
```

This way `next` doesn't get called until your API call has completed, so your middleware will make the request wait and won't render the view until it has the data.